# how to disable a button using a counter in android

Tags: android

I want to disable a button when the user hits the button five times.

Here's the code

```
if(mLatestindex<=4) {
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                mIsCheater = false;
                updateQuestion();
                mFalseButton.setEnabled(true);
                mTrueButton.setEnabled(true);
                mLatestindex++;
            }
}
```

Comment: setEnabled(false)? You meant that? I solved your problem?

Comment: If any of the solutions helped you, consider marking it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `mLatestIndex <= 4` is placed wrongly.
You should check the index inside the Click Listener

```
mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mLatestIndex < 5) {
            // Do the stuff
            // This will execute only if the index is <= 4
        }
        mLatestIndex++;
    }
});
```

This will execute the code only if `mLatestIndex` is less than 5, and increment it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need disable button on 5 times click in general just add global counter and increment it in onClick() with check

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickerCount++;
            if (clickerCount >= 5) {
               button.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
```

If you need to disable view when it was clicked 5 times in certain amount of time, you could store timestamp of last clicked time and compare it with current time